# Jenkins server time behind Linux machine

Tags: linux, jenkins, timezone

I have a jenkins server 1.651.3 running on a RedHat 6.3
Linux OS time is 12:30, but Jenkins server time is 11:30
How can I syncronize Jenkins server time with Linux ? (both should show 12:30)

Note: I tried these workarounds to solve the problem - without success:
1. added

```
-Duser.timezone=Asia/Jerusalem 
-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=Asia/Jerusalem
```

to /etc/sysconfig/jenkins and restarted jenkins service
2. executed

```
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 'Asia/Jerusalem')
```

from Jenkins Script console

Any ideas?

Comment: I finally solved this by setting -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone option to "Europe/Bucharest"

Comment: If you have to resort to such hacks your *system* timezone is probably wrong. Check your /etc/localtime file

Comment: Additionally, if you are dependent on your server or Jenkins to be on a particular time zone - you really should reevaluate your code.  "Local time" is not a server concern.